# Cómo acceder a los nodos hijos para darles estilo en react?

Tags: css, reactjs

Quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```
form > * {
    //instrucciones css
}
```

Pero en react de la siguiente forma:

```
const style = {
    //propiedades de objetos
}
```

Cómo logro acceder a los nodos hijos de una etiqueta en react sin tener que utilizar una hoja de estilos?
En css para acceder a los nodos hijos se utiliza, por ejemplo para acceder a las etiquetas p hijas de una etiqueta div, sería:

```
div > p {

}
```

Quiero hacer eso pero en react, con un objeto, por ejemplo:

```
const estiloDiv = {
    width: '100px',
    display: 'flex'
}
```

y luego añadirle ese objeto a un componente:

```
<div style={estiloDiv}>{props.children}</div>
```

Ahora, lo que quiero es acceder a los hijs de mi componente para darle estilos pero desde estiloDiv, en css se haría de la siguiente forma:

```
div > * {
   margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Quiero hacer la instrucción de arriba, pero en mi objeto estiloDiv

Comment: Si pudieras agregar el código del caso de uso para que la pregunta sea mas descriptiva, saludos

Comment: asignando el estilo directamente no creo que puedas... pero depronto podrías usar styledComponents que si te permite escribir CSS directamente (y no como propiedades de un objeto y que no permite otros operadores de CSS)